# What chess openings should I play If I am an offensive and aggressive chess player?

Tags: opening, learning, strategy, traxler-counter-attack

What chess books should I read If I am an offensive player? I have read a few chess books and they usually are opening books and I'm quite not sure on which openings I should play. Currently, I play the London System and the Sicilian Alpine variation.

I want to know some more openings that are very positional and can lead to games with a lot of chaos and a lot of action. I also want to learn some aggressive openings like the Traxler Counterattack.